# SQL - How to create a Table step by step

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have one main Table [Raw Data which contains postcode as foreign key for other tables]. Then I have table [Geo] which contains col postcode and its corresponding cols lat and lon. Additionally, I have a table which contains col postcode and col type_of_audience. I also have one table which contains col postcode and col trust_value. If I want to LEFT JOIN those information to my main Table [There are 40 more cols for it]. Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Temporary tables are not usually more efficient.

Comment: Vague question. Can you please write more details? @Leo Lin

Comment: Why do you need to have a table that contains other tables? Give us an example.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the separate tables is to prevent duplicating information in the main table. If you put the lat/lon, type_of_audience, and trust_value in the main table, you'd be putting the same info in every row that had the same postcode.

That being said, I think all of the characteristics of the postcode (lat/lon,type_of_audience,trust_value) can be columns in the postcode table. In other words, just one table that describes the postcode, not three. One table to join with the main, not three.